How can I migrate a BLOB column into yugabyte?
We want to switch from MySQL to yugabytedb but have some columns with blob data stored in them (type LONGBLOB).
I see that yugabyte supports BLOB but during migration yugabyte voyager told me that it does not support migration of blob columns.
Can anybody tell me the proper way to migrate those columns to yugabyte?

Large objects are not supported in YugabyteDB and are usually a bad idea in PostgreSQL (old implementation)
You can use the BYTEA datatype for medium size objects (up to 32MB). For large size it is recommended to put then on an object storage with a reference from the database.
If you have seen BLOB as supported, that's probably with the YCQL API (with same limit as YSQL BYTEA)
